# How can a ActiveJob execute rails rake command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I want sidekiq cron job which can run this command

```
rake spec
```

5 times a day...
so I will put a cron job in sidekiq_schedule.yml ,
but how will I execute rake spec ?

I mean how can the ActiveJob execute that rake command from code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever), this will solve your problem, Here is an example

`every 3.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"
  rake "my:rake:task"
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end`